# Disable PopUp disappearing on HomeButton click in Rg.PopUp Xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, popup

How can I disable the PopUp behavior in my App, that makes the PopUp disappear when the homebutton is touched. Specifically I am using an IPad Air as a Device and when I only touch the Homebuttonbar on the Bottom, the PopUp closes. I need this to stop as I want the PopUp only to close when the Ok button is pressed and the user has made a choice…
Thanks

I kinda tried to solve the problem by repepushing the PopUp if it is not closed by the OK Button. But I would like to disable the pop behavior in the first place...

https://youtu.be/Y9eTrOvFdj4

Check the video please to understand the problem, please.

Comment: Please read [ask] before posting.  You haven't included any code to illustrate what you are doing or how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I don’t know what I’m supposed to add for this question. It’s more about preventing an iOS behaviour. Nothing I wrote.

Comment: @Jason I added a Youtube Video which shows the behavior I would like to prevent. Once a card is selected the Ok Button is clickable and is allowed to pop the PopUp. The bar on the Bottom unfortunately pops the PopUp aswell. That's what I would like to prevent. I tried to fix the problem by reputing it on the disappearing method if no card was selected but its not as elegant as I would like it to be... Note that I'm not leaving the page but only pressing the homebar on the bottom...

Answer (score 0):

1. I tried it with iPad Air and iPad Air 2 simulator. When the PopUp page pops up, click the Home button below, and then go back to the App. The result is that the PopUp page is still there. So I'm not sure if your other code is causing this problem.
2. Please check the version of the plugin you are using and update it to the latest version if available.
3. There is an override method(OnResume) in App.cs where you can repop.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, but it’s not exactly the problem I have. It’s not about pressing/swiping the homebutton so that I go back to the homescreen. It’s about tapping the homebar without leaving the app. The gesture pops the popup. And this is the behaviour I need to stop. Thanks alot. I will check the plugin version anyways.

Comment: I used all the methods to bring the app back to the desktop during the test, and the result page is still there. Is it possible that you touched the blank area of the page by mistake when you returned?

Comment: I added a Youtube Video which shows the behavior I would like to prevent. Once a card is selected the Ok Button is clickable and is allowed to pop the PopUp. The bar on the Bottom unfortunately pops the PopUp aswell. That's what I would like to prevent. I tried to fix the problem by reputing it on the disappearing method if no card was selected but its not as elegant as I would like it to be...

Comment: Would you mind sharing us a baisc, minimal project to test ? You can upload it to github and attach the link here.